# Why cant I copy multiple files into one directory?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-3.4, shutil

I am trying to copy multiple files from one directory, into another directory.

```
src_files = os.listdir("srcdir")
print(src_files)
for file_name in src_files:
    full_file_name = os.path.join("srcdir", file_name)
    if (os.path.isfile(full_file_name)):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, "destdir/")
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 539, in <module>
    buildGUI()
  File "script.py", line 385, in buildGUI
    shutil.copy(full_file_name, "destdir/")
  File "/home/opt/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 228, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/home/opt/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 108, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/destdir/'
```

I thought shutil.copy supported a target directory? Thats what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) says.

EDIT:
Based on comment, think I should add that this is Python3.4 on a 64bit Debian Machine.

EDIT2:
As a workaround I'll just use shutil.copytree("sourcedir", "destdir/") which seems to work. I'll leave this question open, and file a bug report or something unless an answer is posted.

Comment: Does it work if you use `destdir` instead of `destdir/`?

Comment: If I omit the "/", it writes into a file "destdir", overwriting it for each file i am trying to copy. The end result is that the contents of "destdir" is the text of the last file in the source files list.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. If the directory already exists, it copies into it whether I end with `/` or not. If the directory doesn't exist, and I end with `/`, it gets an error **No such file or directory**.

Comment: Oh Boy. I'm running python3.4 on a 64bit Debian machine. Could this really be system specific?

Comment: I tried it in python 2.6 on OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: What is inside `srcdir`?

Comment: I took a look at the source code for that version of Python, and it seems that `os.path.isdir` must be returning false for your destination directory to get the error you are getting.

Comment: Tried your code snippet on 64-bit Debian (unstable) without any problems. It runs with Python 3.4 and 2.7 with and without trailing slash like expected. Perhaps try it with a ``srcdir`` and ``destdir``. In another context, I had a similar problem because the filename encoding was not uft-8.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it either.  Your code looks good.

Comment: Can you `tar` up a minimal pair of directories that  cause this?

Comment: Could you post a solution to your problem or close/delete the question if it was a typographical error.